# virtuemart configuration

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I want to configure VirtueMart. I just need to configure three things:

1. Disable email validation when checkout
2. Add 8% shipping cost to all products
3. Add 8.25% taxes to state of Texas

how can i do that.(in administrator panel, not coding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of these are built in setting in either VM or Joomla.

1. To disable email confirmation, in the Joomla admin go to Site > global configuration > user settings > New User Account Activation set to No
2. In VM, Store menu > Shipping Module List > Flex > Configure Ship Method > select amount to be used for shipping fees
3. In VM, Tax menu > List Tax Rates > USA > change state and tax percentage to your needs.